# Add laravel to path (Linux Mint 18.2 sonya)

Tags: linux, bash, laravel, path, linux-mint

I'm trying to use the shortcut "laravel new site" on bash but i got "laravel: command not found".

I already installed laravel by composer, and tried like 5 different ways to add this to PATH.

I added:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

On the last line of bashrc, rebooted, still not working.

Comment: When you edit **.bashrc** file, run `source ~/.bashrc` to reload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [laravel installation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation)

> Make sure to place the $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin directory (or the equivalent directory for your OS) in your $PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system.

So, instead of

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

try

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

When you edit **.bashrc** file, run command `source ~/.bashrc` to reload changes